# Designing a big data web app

Tags: design, distributed-system, big-data

How do you design a website that allows users to query a large amount of user data, more specifically:

- there are ~100 million users with ~100TB of data, data is stored in [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/) (not a database)
- number of (concurrent) queries is not important, but each query should be as fast as possible
- support some simple queries such as: get user info by id, get
  accumulated data like monthly logins and monthly online time
- query result is little (1 number, or a few hundred rows) so frontend performance doesn't matter

I'm more interested in the thought process on how to approach this requirement. For example:

- at 100 users, what is the design?
- at 1,000,000 users, what needs to be changed?
- at 100,000,000 users, what is the design now?

I've searched around and see a lot of people talking about caching, load balancing,... Of course, those techniques are useful and can be used but how do you know it can help handling N users? Nobody seems to explain this point.

Comment: You haven’t told us much about the results of the queries, which is what matters in the context of web sites. For example, if you run a search over the 100 million users and return a single value in 100ms, then all of the engineering effort is going to be on the back end and doesn’t really have anything to do with web sites. However if you need to display a table with a million rows, that’s a different problem. So you need to be more specific.

Comment: You're are right, that is an important part. I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. Now I want to ask you a question— forget the web site part. How would you make this work if the queries were submitted at the command line?

Comment: I would setup something that allows SQL queries and can connect with HDFS, for example [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/). I will add more servers until it cannot go faster. Then to save time on the same query later, I cache the result.

Comment: great. Now you know what you need to build: an interface for defining queries that can be submitted to Spark.

Comment: @RibaldEddie didn't I just basically answer my question... I think the key point is to go from the most basic approach like the terminal and keep adding improvements. Thanks for your help. If only I have enough rep to upvote your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly basic math.

The bottleneck is unlikely your database, but bandwidth.

Take your max bandwidth, divide by expected # of users, and subtract 15% for overhead.

If you really have unlimited bandwidth, then do the same calculation using your database throughput.

Answer (score 1):

At this time in cloud tech, I would employ what others have already designed to handle data loads.  Though you have a bit of data, I would put these data and future records into something akin to [Google's BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/):

- Easy to query via SQL,
- Pay by query,
- Handles many, many pebibytes,
- Easily embedded into web/mobile app,
- Maintains [cache already](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results),

By design, there is some non-cached query inertia time, but I would run away fast from trying to design, scale, script, pay-for, and maintain all the above.